# Bookmarklet - Add an input to middle of a URL?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

This is probably extremely simple but I am a total newbie. I use something like this to add an input to the end of an URL

```
javascript:
(function() { 
    var val= prompt("Enter #",""); 
    if (val) 
        location="http://www.test.com?param="+escape(val);
})()
```

But now I want to add something to the middle of another url like:

```
http://www.test.com/ENTERSOMETHINGHERE/html/stuff/
```

I have no clue what I am doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just concatenate the strings together:

```
javascript:
(function() { 
    var val= prompt("Enter #",""); 
    if (val) 
        location="http://www.test.com/"+escape(val)+"/html/stuff";
})()
```